# Print exponential value as a string without expanding

Tags: javascript

```
var y = 123e5;
console.log(y); // output: 12300000
```

Above code has a number variable `y` and the output I get is `12300000`. I would like to show it same but as a string. Output should be '123e5' and the type of value also be string. The requirement for such question is that I do not want JS to manipulate my data until I require And If it does than there might also be a way to get the exact value I stored/wrote.

Test values for `y` can also be taken as `1023e5`, `1023e+5`, `1023e+5`, `10230e+5`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<pre>
<script>
var y = 123e5;
document.writeln(y);
document.writeln(123e5);
document.writeln(123e+5);
document.writeln(123e-5);
document.writeln(1230e-5);
</script>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```

*My exact objective was to know that if there is any way I can get the same value stored/wrote without change.So what is the exact way to get my original value.*

Thanks!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Not actually a duplicate of that as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My exact objective was to know that if there is any way I can get the
>   same value stored/wrote without change.So what is the exact way to get
>   my original value.

No, that information is *lost*. The scientific notation in JavaScript is to make it clearer to express some *difficult* numbers (very big/small) in source code. If you intend to always know *how* the value was defined in its specific notation, you will need to use strings or attach some extra information to store it.

However, here is a function that converts trailing `0` of a number into the `eN` equivalent, how the notation works in JavaScript with numbers.

```js
var convertNumToExpStr = function(number) {
  return String(number).replace(/0+$/, function(all) {
    return 'e' + all.length;
  });
};

document.body.textContent = convertNumToExpStr(123e5);
```

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Sorry I don't post here often and haven't learned how that works yet.

Comment: What if `convertNumToExpStr(123e5+1);` ?

Comment: @alex Thanks! you're almost there but if i change the value than it doesn't output as expected... Can you please check you code for the value `1023e5`

Comment: @hallucinations it wouldn't change the represented number as there isn't any trailing `0`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I guess its better to give Fiddle link and add important code that adding entire code snippet in answer. But yes, this is for answers where code snippet is too long.

Comment: @RJ Works for me, gives `'1023e5'`.

Comment: @alex does not work for me it gives `12300001`, i use fiddle haha
https://jsfiddle.net/szdcgs54/

Comment: @Rajesh Nah, don't be lazy. It's **absolutely better to have the entire resource in SO in order to avoid that a downtime of external resources would be a problem for future readers when looking for a solution**. With a code snippet here you can even run it in place...

Comment: @alex I've edited your answer to show you how it works. Feel free to check it and learn how you would do it yourself :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer twist you edited it wrong and break the answer. joke

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi That's the expected output because there are no trailing zeroes.

Comment: we should shut up, this guy has 243K repu haha

Comment: This works fine. My exact objective was to know that if there is any way I can get the same value stored/wrote without change. So the above code is good for a particular pattern but its not perfect to get the value of all other pattern like `1023e5`, `1023e+5`, `1023e+5`, `10230e+5` and so on... So what is the exact way to get my original value. I've also updated my Question

Comment: @RJ What are you doing exactly? The scientific notation in JavaScript is to make it clearer to express some numbers in source code.